# Whats the fundamental difference between addressing of array[di] and [array + di] in assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, emu8086

Given is the assembly program of Intel 8086 Processor which adds the numbers in array:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    array dw 1,2,3,1,2
    sum   dw ?,", is the sum!$"

.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov di,0

    repeat:
    mov ax,[array+di]
    add sum,ax
    add di,2           ; Increment di with 2 since array is of 2 bytes

    cmp di,9
    jbe repeat         ; jump if di<=9

    add sum,30h        ; Convert to ASCII
    mov ah,09h
    mov dx,offset sum  ; Printing sum
    int 21h

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
end  main
```

Above program adds the number of array using "base + index" addressing mode.

The same operation can by performed by something like:

```
mov ax, array[di]
```

Now I have following questions here:

1. What's the difference between `array[di]` and `[array+di]`
2. Which memory addressing mode is `array[di]`?
3. Which one is better to use and why?

Comment: There is no difference, but the standard syntax is `[array+di]`. Some assemblers also accept the other version.

Comment: "3." is heavily opinion based, as your assembler dictates what you can use... I would go with `[array+di]` because A) IIRC that's the official way how Intel syntax was defined by Intel B) it's compatible with NASM - which looks to be one of ultimate assemblers for x86, ie. maintained, multi platform, multi target and open source. And even cost-free. Hard to beat that combo. C) makes more sense to me, I'm used to think rather in pointers than in "variables", concept of variables was shown to me after I already did know Z80 assembler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the book [The Art of Assembly Language](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html), `array[di]` and `[array + di]` are both "indexed addresing modes", so, none is better than the other, is just different syntax for the same thing. The section [4.6.2.3 Indexed Addressing Modes](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH04/CH04-2.html#HEADING2-54) of the book explains that the important thing is **the presence of a constant value and an index (or base) register** :

> The indexed addressing modes use the following syntax:
>
> ```
>             mov     al, disp[bx]
>             mov     al, disp[bp]
>             mov     al, disp[si]
>             mov     al, disp[di]
> ```
>
> The offsets generated by these addressing modes are the **sum** of the constant and the specified register.
>
> [image]
>
> You may substitute **si** or **di** in the figure above to obtain the [si+disp] and [di+disp] addressing modes.

We are calling "constant value" to the variable `array` because variables are offsets in data segment (so they are constant values), as explained [here](http://www.yecd.com/os/8086%20assembler%20tutorial%20for%20beginners%20(part%203).htm) :

> Variable is a memory location. For a programmer it is much easier to
>   have some value be kept in a variable named "var1" than at the address
>   5A73:235B.

It is important to mention that different assemblers may use different syntax for the same addressing modes, for example, [MASM vs NASM](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/mp/f99/mp5/masm_nasm.html), or [NASM vs GAS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm/).

There are other addressing modes that change the size (in bytes) and performance (in clock cycles) of the instructions involved, as can be read [here](http://www.oocities.org/mc_introtocomputers/Instruction_Timing.PDF). Next is instruction `MOV` and the addressing modes :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are those cycle counts for 8086?  I doubt that's relevant, unless emu8086 is actually a cycle-accurate simulator (which I highly doubt).

Comment: Anyway, it's not just that they're both "indexed addressing modes", they're literally the same addressing mode.  It's just a different asm syntax for the same machine code.  Oh, I missed part2 of the question, yeah I guess all this stuff explaining that addressing mode is relevant.